# Handling YouTube no video thumbnail

Tags: php

I have the following code that checks to see if a YouTube thumbnail image exists, displays it if it does and displays "Not found" text if it doesn't.

All works fine except it's super slow to run.

```
$videos = array('https://img.youtube.com/vi/-mX5p8K8CDc/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/zp72WjMVhTQ/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/pbtgNVykEpg/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/mhWeWxkKwak/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/Vao7T4__0Xw/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/QABXqo5Z78w/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/lvViuv0vIKU/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/q7lDSPiuEmY/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/hOrcWFZ-q-4/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/z-PluBrYvg0/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/d7iwV1vr5_8/hqdefault.jpg','https://img.youtube.com/vi/v8A0ad_2mPc/hqdefault.jpg');

foreach ($videos as $video) {
    if (@getimagesize($video)) {
    echo "<img src='$video'><br>";
    } else {
    echo "Not found";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Does anyone know of another faster way to do this? Doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: You maybe should cache files on your server, and use `file_exists()` instead of `getimagesize()`. And make the "grab" process once.

Comment: I went with your suggestion and so much faster. Just need to perform housekeeping jobs in the background to remove any dead links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send a HEAD request and validate the response HTTP status.

```
curl --head 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/zp72WjMVhTQ/hqdefault.jpg'
```

Response on existing image:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  # this is what you're interested in
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
...
```

Response on non-existing image:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  # this is what you're interested in
Vary: Origin
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
...
```

`getimagesize()` needs to download the whole file to tmp, and perform other slow calculations, which you don't need for your use case.

Comment: I'm not familiar curl but will take a look. Thanks

Comment: It's also supported in PHP, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I gave this a go and it is definitely quicker but still too slow unfortunately. Went with @Syscall's idea and now it's super fast.